# iframe seems to break css layout

Tags: html, css, iframe

Can anyone say why this is wrong? I thought the yellow div would be across the whole page like the pink div. But when I look at it - no, the yellow div lines up under the image not the whole length.

```
<div style=width:100%;background:pink>
    fjadlskjfdsf dslkfsda sdjkfh
</div>
<div style=width:100%;background:red>
    <div style=width:60%;float:left>
        <img src=Library_left.jpg width=100%>
    </div>
    <div style=width:40%;float:right>
        <iFrame scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://silib2.net/eResources/scripts/carousel/carousel.php">&nbsp;</iFrame>
    </div>
</div>
<div style=width:100%;background:yellow>
    <h1 style=text-align:center>adslkjfasdlkjf</h1>
why is this div not wider?
</div>
```

( https://silib2.net/eResources/scripts/carousel/form.htm )

It is probably something stupid?

Comment: Add float:none to your yellow div.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This:-

```
<div style=width:100%;background:pink>
    fjadlskjfdsf dslkfsda sdjkfh
</div>
<div style="width:100%;background:red; clear: both; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=width:60%;float:left>
        <img src=Library_left.jpg width=100%>
    </div>
    <div style=width:40%;float:right>
        <iFrame scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://silib2.net/eResources/scripts/carousel/carousel.php">&nbsp;</iFrame>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%;background:yellow; clear: both; overflow: hidden;">
    <h1 style=text-align:center>adslkjfasdlkjf</h1>
why is this div not wider?
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Static Height to Iframe May solve your issue

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="165px" src="https://silib2.net/eResources/scripts/carousel/carousel.php">&nbsp;</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your iframe a smaller height which would be approximately

```
    height: 225px;
```

And you need to give the div that wraps it [one with red background on it]

```
  clear:both; Overflow:hidden;
```